# Why is type not exiting correctly?

Tags: sikuli

I am trying get Sikuli to open a chat window in a game(using t) and then close it without typing anything in (using enter).

But when I run the script Sikulu opens the menu and then types tt, then it closes the menu.

I put a delay of 1 second in between the type t and type enter in case it was running too fast but it did not help.

```
    while True:
        type("t")
        sleep (1)
        type(Key.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you running this in a loop. If you want to perform 2 actions:

1. Open chat (by hitting "t")
2. Close chat (by hitting "t")

Just do it outside the loop, simply like this:

```
type("t") 
#some delay to ensure the menu has opened
type("t")
```

The proper way to do that though is to implicitly wait for the menu to appear. So if you can define a pattern that you can use as a reliable indicator, use it like this:

```
type("t")
wait(pattern, waitTime)
type("t")
```

Comment: I want to run it again and again to stop myself going idle in game. Do I have to wait for a pattern to get this to work?

Comment: In that case you just need to make sure that you are allowing enough time for the pages and elements to load. Please refer to the second part of my answer where I mentioned that you should define some use as an indicator of page or element has been loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot wait for an element, the next element I will see is me being kicked from the game.

Comment: Well the chat menu can be this element. The initial problem you are describing in your question (regards typing "tt") is most likely to occur due to the fact that you perform all these actions too fast.The key here is to add adequate sleep times.

Comment: I've added up to 15 seconds sleep times, the weird thing is sometimes it works as expected, most of the time it does not, seems like a bug with Sikuli itself, I will try again with some conditions.